# Transforming SQL into Doctrine Query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

### Transforming SQL into Doctrine Query

I have this raw SQL query that I have a hard time transforming to a Doctrine Query.
My goal is to get The Influencer that have applied to The offer.

I have a `ManyToMany` relationship between the entities  `Application and Influencer`.

```
SELECT * FROM application 
LEFT JOIN application_influencer
ON application_influencer.application_id = application.id
```

### APPLICATION ENTITY

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ApplicationRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ApplicationRepository::class)
 */
class Application
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Influencer::class, inversedBy="applications")
     */
    private $influencerId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Offer::class, inversedBy="application")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $offer;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->influencerId = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Influencer[]
     */
    public function getInfluencerId(): Collection
    {
        return $this->influencerId;
    }

    public function addInfluencerId(Influencer $influencerId): self
    {
        if (!$this->influencerId->contains($influencerId)) {
            $this->influencerId[] = $influencerId;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeInfluencerId(Influencer $influencerId): self
    {
        $this->influencerId->removeElement($influencerId);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(?string $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOffer(): ?Offer
    {
        return $this->offer;
    }

    public function setOffer(?Offer $offer): self
    {
        $this->offer = $offer;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

### INFLUENCER ENTITY

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\InfluencerRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=InfluencerRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("username", message="Ce pseudo est déjà utilisé")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Influencer
{
    const SERVER_PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER = '/public/uploads';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $socialNetwork = [
        'Website' => '',
        'Instagram' => '',
        'Tiktok' => '',
        'Facebook' => '',
        'Youtube' => '',
        'Twitter' => '',
        'Twitch' => ''
    ];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="integer",
     *     message="Vous ne pouvez pas mettre de lettre, mettez des chiffres"
     * )
     */
    private $siret;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Application::class, mappedBy="influencerId")
     */
    private $applications;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Contract::class, mappedBy="influencerId")
     */
    private $brandId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Regex("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i", message="Vous ne pouvez pas mettre d'espace")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true)
     */
    private $type = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $profilePhoto;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="cover_image_user", fileNameProperty="profilePhoto")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="influencer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $UserId;





    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->applications = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->brandId = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * toString
     * @return string
     */

/*    public function __toString()
    {
        if(is_null($this->applications)){
            return 'NULL';
        }
        return $this->applications;
    }*/

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function getSocialNetwork(): ?array
    {
        return $this->socialNetwork;
    }

    public function setSocialNetwork(array $socialNetwork): self
    {
        $this->socialNetwork = $socialNetwork;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSiret(): ?int
    {
        return $this->siret;
    }

    public function setSiret(?int $siret): self
    {
        $this->siret = $siret;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Application[]
     */
    public function getApplications(): Collection
    {
        return $this->applications;
    }

    public function addApplication(Application $application): self
    {
        if (!$this->applications->contains($application)) {
            $this->applications[] = $application;
            $application->addInfluencerId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeApplication(Application $application): self
    {
        if ($this->applications->removeElement($application)) {
            $application->removeInfluencerId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Contract[]
     */
    public function getBrandId(): Collection
    {
        return $this->brandId;
    }

    public function addBrandId(Contract $brandId): self
    {
        if (!$this->brandId->contains($brandId)) {
            $this->brandId[] = $brandId;
            $brandId->setInfluencerId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBrandId(Contract $brandId): self
    {
        if ($this->brandId->removeElement($brandId)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($brandId->getInfluencerId() === $this) {
                $brandId->setInfluencerId(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(?string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?array
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(?array $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfilePhoto(): ?string
    {
        return $this->profilePhoto;
    }

    public function setProfilePhoto(?string $profilePhoto): self
    {
        $this->profilePhoto = $profilePhoto;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param null|File $imageFile
     * @return User
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;
        // permet a vich de savoir si l'image est nouvelle ou pas.
        if ($image) {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserId(): ?User
    {
        return $this->UserId;
    }

    public function setUserId(?User $UserId): self
    {
        $this->UserId = $UserId;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

### OFFER ENTITY

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\OfferRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OfferRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Offer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $description;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz")
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz")
     *@Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual("tomorrow", message="Une offre peut commencer qu'à partir de demain.")
     *@Assert\GreaterThan(propertyPath="dateCreation", message="Une offre ne peut pas être inférieure à la date de publication.")
     *@Assert\LessThanOrEqual(propertyPath="dateEnd", message="La date de commencement doit être inférieure à la date de fin.")
     */
    private $dateStart;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz")
     *@Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual("tomorrow")
     *@Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyPath="dateStart", message="La date de fin doit être supérieure à la date de commencement.")
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      minPropertyPath = "dateStart",
     *      max = "+5 years"
     * )
     */
    private $dateEnd;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $field = [];


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Brand::class, inversedBy="offers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $brandId;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Application::class, mappedBy="offer", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $application;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->application = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getDateCreation(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateCreation;
    }

    /**
     * Gets triggered only on insert

     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setDateCreation(): void
    {
        $this->dateCreation = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    public function getDateStart(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateStart;
    }

    public function setDateStart(\DateTimeInterface $dateStart): self
    {
        $this->dateStart = $dateStart;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateEnd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateEnd;
    }

    public function setDateEnd(\DateTimeInterface $dateEnd): self
    {
        $this->dateEnd = $dateEnd;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getField(): ?array
    {
        return $this->field;
    }

    public function setField(array $field): self
    {
        $this->field = $field;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getBrandId(): ?Brand
    {
        return $this->brandId;
    }

    public function setBrandId(?Brand $brandId): self
    {
        $this->brandId = $brandId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Application[]
     */
    public function getApplication(): Collection
    {
        return $this->application;
    }

    public function addApplication(Application $application): self
    {
        if (!$this->application->contains($application)) {
            $this->application[] = $application;
            $application->setOffer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeApplication(Application $application): self
    {
        if ($this->application->removeElement($application)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($application->getOffer() === $this) {
                $application->setOffer(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: your mapping is questionable. call your property (and getter, setter, ...) influencer (getInfluencer, setInfluencer, ...) because that's what you do. Entity properties DO NOT have to match the columns. repeat for other properties. it'll be sooo frustrating otherwise. after you have done that `SELECT * FROM App\Entity\Application application LEFT JOIN application.influencer` however, you should really take a look at doctrine-dql for further information, instead of blindly trial and error.

Comment: Okay thank you ! I will take all you're comments into consideration